# Adding Notes Using Google Reader's API

Tags: api, google-reader

Does anyone know how to add a note using Google Reader's API? In looking at some of their code, I've noticed that it might have something to do with the "/reader/api/0/item/edit" URL, but I can't find this documented anywhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do a POST to http://www.google.com/reader/api/0/item/edit

You'll need to add your SID cookie, and also get a token from the API for it to work.

Params are:

T = token string

share = make the note public, "true" or "false" values

snippet = the body of the note

There's also a "linkify" parameter, although I haven't been able to figure out yet what that one actually does.

Comment: The SID method is no longer supported - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6239560/

Answer (score 5):

The answer above is missing the full set of query parameters.

They are documented here: http://www.google.com/support/reader/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=147149

Comment: Unofficial documentation is here: http://code.google.com/p/pyrfeed/wiki/GoogleReaderAPI

Answer (score 3):

Here is what works for me:

```
POST http://www.google.com/reader/api/0/item/edit
ck=<time>
client=<client>
share=true
annotation=<text>
T=<token>
srcItemId=<itemid>
```